# What is more historically correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation, math-history, substitution

I was wondering what was formally correct, when resolving an integral by substitution, use as a new variable $t$ or $u$? I noticed that here in Italy we use $t$, while I saw that abroad (e.g USA) use $u$.
When was this variable method of integration designed?

I am aware that I can use any variable and that the result would be the same but I'm curious to know originally what was used by Newton, Leibniz, etc.

I hope someone knows how to answer, it is an unresolved doubt that I have for some time.

Comment: @T.Bongers Did you read the question at all? "I am aware that I can use any variable and that the result would be the same but I'm curious to know originally what was used by Newton, Leibniz, etc." -- a direct quote from the question/

Comment: Thanks, @Yanko I Have added the tag

Comment: for what it's worth I think the tan $x = t/2$ substitution (attributed in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to Euler then Weierstrass has used $t$ for a long long time, was always taught it was old and originated in that form but haven't seen the original sources, just an example I guess and I don't know what was popular when the technique was actually discovered

Comment: (sorry typo $t=$ tan $(x/2)$ gah)

Comment: if you google "katz change of variables in multiple integrals Euler to Cartan" you'll get a pdf link to [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689856?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which seems to indicate $x = x(t, v)$ and $y =y(t, v)$ as being historically popular in the 2-d setting, oh well, hope someone can give you a proper answer!

Comment: I found this in the Italian wiki:
[link](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrazione_per_sostituzione)
while doing the same research but in English I find this:
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)
so once again the question is: t or u?

Comment: Not sure how valid this is but worth noting most of the calculus Newton did used $t$ as the main variable (as he was dealing with physical problems which changed with time), and so couldn’t have used $t$ as a substitution variable

Comment: You can see [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/is-it-true-that-leibniz-introduced-constant-variable-and-function) for the link to Newton and Leibniz original papers.

Comment: We can see an example of [change of variables](https://books.google.it/books?id=BFqWNwpfqo8C&pg=PA228) from Euler (1769): as we can see, there is a change from the original $x$ and $y$ expressing them as functions of the new $u$ and $v$. The choice of the new "names" seems quite straightforward : the "right-hand" part of the alphabet : $u,v,x,y,z$ was used since Descartes for *variables*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA
thank you very much for your answer, it is very useful

Comment: You are welcome :-)